# Using a custom loss function that references some of the inputs of the NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm having trouble implementing a custom loss function into a Neural Network I'm building in TensorFlow.  I want use one of my features as part of the loss function, so I've tried using `model.add_loss` instead of giving loss a value in the `model.compile` function.

My data looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers


feature_df  = np.array([600,9])

training, test, = feature_df[:350,:], feature_df[350:,:]
x_train = training[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
y_train = training[:,8]
loss_inp_train = training[:,[6]]


x_test = test[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
y_test = test[:,8]
loss_inp_test = test[:,[6]]
```

I want to use a custom loss function because its not necessarily the mse I'm interested in minimizing, I want to minimize the profitability of this model, which depends if y_true and y_pred fall above or below `loss_inp_train`

I've tried creating a loss function that looks like this

```
def custom_loss(y_pred, y_true,inp):
    loss = 0
    if (y_pred < inp):
        if y_true < inp:
            loss = loss + .9
        else:
            loss = loss - 1
    else:
        if y_true > inp:
            loss = loss + .9
        else:
            loss = loss - 1
    loss = loss*-1
    return(loss)
```

And the Model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    normalize,
  layers.Dense(18),
  layers.Dense(1)
  
])

model.add_loss(profit_loss(y_pred,y_train,loss_inp_train))
model.compile(loss = None,
                    optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam())
```

I'm having trouble feeding the loss function the output of the model. I'm still new to TensorFlow, whenever I've accessed predicted values its after the training using `model.predict`, but obviously I don't have a fitted model yet.  How do I reference both a feature of the training data and y_true, y_pred in a function?

Comment: Technical issue aside, your loss function is a form of step function, which has zero gradient almost everywhere. As a result, you won't be able to train this NN using gradient descent.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to define a custom loss. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to handle nested if statements like you have. Probably with a combination of `K.switch`. I can try to give you a partial solutions taking in consideration only the presence of a single if statement. Let's take the following simplified code:

```
loss = 0
if (y_pred < inp):
    loss = # assignment 1
else:
    loss = # assignment 2
```

In this case the loss function could be converted into this:

```
def profit_loss(inp):
    def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):    
        loss = 0 
        condition = K.greater(y_pred - inp, 0)
        loss1 = # assignment 1 if y_pred < inp
        loss2 = # assignment 2 if y_pred >= inp
        loss = K.switch(condition, loss2, loss1)
        return - K.sum(loss)

    return loss_function

model.compile(optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss=profit_loss(inp))
```

This way `y_true` and `y_pred` are automatically handled and you just have to feed the `inp` argument.

Hope this helps getting you closer to solving the problem.

Comment: probably worth posting a runnable example of `profit_loss`...

Comment: I got this error when I tried it `ValueError: condition of if statement expected to be `tf.bool` scalar, got Tensor("loss_function/Less:0", shape=(350, 1), dtype=bool); to check for None, use `is not None`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I realized just now that if statements won't work like this with tensors. You'll have to use Keras backend utilities for it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312070/custom-loss-function-in-keras-tensorflow-with-if-statement) for example. I can try to fix it in a few hours @ProfQuack

Comment: @ProfQuack unfortunately I'm not sure on how to convert nested if statements to work as a loss function. I've updated the answer to give you some suggestions

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar type of PNL loss function and I've made it a bit farther than you have but I'm now getting a different error. "No gradients provided for any variable"